# How to Deploy Electron React Boilerplate App?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I made a React Electron application and I  have difficulty deploying this Electron React Boilerplate App (make a .exe file) I use this  Boilerplate: https://github.com/Jerga99/electron-react-boilerplate?

[image]

my package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "electron-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "y",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "make_targets": {
        "win32": [
          "squirrel"
        ],
        "darwin": [
          "zip"
        ],
        "linux": [
          "deb",
          "rpm"
        ]
      },
      "electronPackagerConfig": {
        "packageManager": "npm"
      },
      "electronWinstallerConfig": {
        "name": "electron_react_app"
      },
      "electronInstallerDebian": {},
      "electronInstallerRedhat": {},
      "github_repository": {
        "owner": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      "windowsStoreConfig": {
        "packageName": "",
        "name": "electronreactapp"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use Electron frog, but I get this error:

[image]

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong or suggest another way to deploying this electron app?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Electron builder instead of electron forge.
https://www.electron.build/

Also, The boilerplate you are using has only 2 commits which means that it is not maintained. So the boilerplate itself can have bugs.

I suggest you use this react boilerplate: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate